# In Judaism is there an idea that women are more grounded

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, women, middos-character-traits

Does Judaism see Jewish woman as more down to earth,
regarding money (their support) more in a more physical way then men (the supporters),
clearing about their support more then religious questions?

I thought so but @mevaqesh made me question my understanding.

(Sources which seem to show this
Rashi on [beraishis 34.3](http://chabad.org/8229#v=3&showrashi=true).

Rambam [teshuva 10.1,5](http://chabad.org/911914).

The idea that you need to support with your things your wife more then you can afford since she is trusting on you (and not Hashem directly) , but you yourself should trust Hashem directly.
[Pischai Teshuva Even Haezer  2.6](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=eh_x7494)  that the girl needs to understand that Torah brings good in to this physical world (IE money) and if she does not, she will not let her husband learn, so the physical is very important to women).

If I remember more examples I will b"n add some

Comment: IIRC, there is a notion that women have more "foresight" than me do. I'm not sure if this is restricted to family matters, specifically. The example I recall comes from Sarah who suggest to Abraham to exile Hagar and Yishma'el. Abraham hesitated to do so and G-d says, "Listen to everything Sarah says". For my own info, is this along the lines to answering your question? I don't quite follow what you are seeking.

Comment: @DanF yes it seems to be a connected idea, to better see where my question is coming from see the comments here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78903/5120

Comment: Regarding the utter irrelevance of that Rashi, see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78903/should-a-man-be-humble-before-his-woman-wife-date-or-should-he-boast?noredirect=1#comment238182_78903).

Comment: This asks about Judaism's view. What sort of proofs are you looking for? How are we supposed to differentiate Judaism's view on this (which may or may not exist) from those of individual Jews?

Comment: @mevaqesh I guess by bringing sources which are respect by many Jews, so it becomes not the view of that sposific writer but of Judaism (why is this question different then other questions in this regard?)

Comment: I am not sure how being respected makes you the spokesman for all of Judaism. (BTW the word is 'specific' not 'sposific'; consider using a spell-checker). | This question is different form many others, since Judaism doesn't necessarily have an expressed opinion on the matter; unlike, for example a halakhic question. | `are the example [sic] not that they want the phisical [sic] now, and that the spiritual detail [sic] get easily forgettin [sic] by them` Rather than asking me, why not find the sources yourself, and see whether this is the case; even editing in a source would help.

Comment: To repeat, Rambam did not think of women as being equal. However there is no reason to think of that as his Judaism based opinion, any more than his disbelief in Uranus. Both beliefs of his were shared by pretty much everyone in the world at the time. The latter is universally accepted today, in spite of his contrary view. Many would similarly view the former view.

Comment: Women are described as having greater binah but a "lighter" da'as. Those are two intellectual skills, fundamental terms whose definitions are the topic of dispute between schools of qabbalah and between qabbalah and various other schools of Jewish Thought. On the topic of worldliness, I would have said that if anything, women are described as more spiritual and LESS worldly than men.

Comment: Also see BM 59a