# Kiddush for someone who can't talk

Tags: halacha, medicine, menora-chanukia, kiddush, motzi-yedei-chovato

Someone has had his voice box removed and therefore cannot talk.

Should his wife be making kiddush (havdala perhaps not) or lighting Chanukah lights for him rather than him doing it himself and only mouthing the words?

Is it better or equal for him to be just mouthing the blessing or is it better to hear it from someone else, in this case his wife?

Comment: For those who did not know that women are chayav in kiddush: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7116/women-making-kiddush

Comment: @patient He _can_ be yotze through his wife's recitation of kiddush; see the [Aruch HaShulchan 271:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9101&st=&pgnum=90).

Comment: I am aware of that. My question is if he is mechuyav to do it this way. Or with chanuka lights should she make the b'rocho and light.

Comment: Related Teshuvas Radvaz (Siman 867), re is a blind man obligated to have someone be motzi him שנים מקרא ואחד תרגום. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%22%D7%AA_%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%91%22%D7%96/%D7%AA%D7%AA%D7%A1%D7%96

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, even with the voice box removed, **a person can whisper and can hear himself whisper**. This is more than enough to allow him to fulfill the commandment.

Note, that for commandments that require an action, like putting Teffilin or lighting Channuka candles, **the reciting of the blessing is not crucial**. Only for commandments, where the saying **is** the commandment, like the Sabbath Kiddush, he could say in whisper or be Yotze from his wife or kids or anyone else obligated him/herself.

Comment: In my personal experience I can only mouth words but not whisper and certainly not hear myself whisper. When I  go to hospital I either have to @Al Berko type which I can do quite fast or I have a person there who can read my mouth.My writing isnt the best. True the b'rocho is not meakev, but it is better to make a mitsva with a b'rocho. Therefore I consider the wife should rather light the chanuka menora. The gemoro also gives this mitsva to the wife sometimes.

Comment: If this is a personal issue, you have to consult a rav, as the box in the top right says.

Comment: "This is more than enough.." that sounds legit, because for comparison by the Amidah al pi Zohar צלותא אשתמע לאודנין דבר נש, לית מאן דציית לה לעילא -- Prayer that's heard by mortals, nobody Above listens to it (some interpret meaning it shouldn't even be heard by his own ears, i.e. a whisper inaudible to his own ears)